Warcraft Lua 1.12 (Turtle Wow) GetSpellCooldown doesn't work
The following scripts return the same error "Invalid spell slot in GetSpellCooldown"
/script  print(GetSpellCooldown(10335, "spell"))

The id '20216' is the id of 'Holy Strike' in turtle wow:
https://database.turtle-wow.org/?spell=10335
The above scriptlet works if I use the id for 'Divine Shield':
/script  print(GetSpellCooldown(1020, "spell"))

I must be missing something obvious:
https://wowwiki-archive.fandom.com/wiki/API_GetSpellCooldown

Well as it turns out the correct id for 'Holy Strike' is 65. So the correct version of the scriptlet is:
/script  local start_time, duration, enabled = GetSpellCooldown(65, BOOKTYPE_SPELL); print(start_time); print(duration); print(enabled);

